# how to ignore certificates check in snap on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

am trying to install wekan on ubuntu but when i do

```
sudo snap install wekan
```

i get certificates warning

```
> - Download snap "core" (6531) from channel "stable" (Get https://fastly.cdn.snapcraft.io/download-origin/fastly/99T7MUlRhtI3U0QFgl5mXXESAiSwt776_6531.snap?token=1552986000_f5f9bd27ddd6a5fcdb342af604507b93bfd50383:
> x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid)
```

so i wonder how to bypass the certificates check i know with wget we use --no-check-certificate flag to bypass certificates check so i wonder what is the flag for snap

Comment: I'm getting this at the moment on 18.04. But only on some instances. And if I run `sudo apt update` on the node with this error, it tells me that `bionic-updates` is specifically invalid until about 12 hours in the future. I haven't looked closely at the certificate, but it's possible that this issue can occur from a rolling update of certificates in their cluster, and the coincidental paired server instance matters.

Answer (score 2):

Try to check the Date / Time because it was my issue. I set the date and time and snap start working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. To fix I've installed and enabled **ntp** service (*network time protocol*) and ran **dpkg-reconfigure tzdata** (*timezone database*) to set a correct timezone. *Snap install* should work like a charm. No need to bypass certificate check.